Is Pro Wrestling Halal?
Is professional wrestling halal? I want a Yes or No answer for this question. I am a Sunni Muslim. If it is halal to become a pro wrestler, I want to become a pro wrestler.

There is a difference between traditional wrestling and professional wrestling.
Competing in traditional wresting is halal according to many scholars (Al-Mughni, Radd al-Muhtar, Al-Azeez Sharh al-Wajeez), as long as there is no other haram act involved. Some have even held that it is permissible to have a wrestling competition with prizes (with some conditions to distinguish it from gambling). The reason is that such wresting is mentioned in a hadith and because it has a benefit i.e. it is practice for close combat in Jihad.
Professional wrestling, on the other hand, is simply a scripted show put on for entertainment. There isn't any clear benefit in it and it is not one of the permissible activities or competitions mentioned directly or implied in the ahadith such as:

كل ما يلهو به الرجل المسلم باطل إلا رميه بقوسه وتأديبه فرسه وملاعبته أهله
All idle pastimes that the Muslim man engages in are falsehood, except for his shooting of his bow, his training of his horse, and his playing with his wife, for they are from truth.
— Jami at-Tirmidhi


لا سبق إلا في نصل أو حافر أو خف
There should be no awards* (for victory in a competition) except for arrows (archery), camels or horses (racing).
—  Nasai and Jami at-Tirmidhi -    (* some interpret this to mean any competition even without an award)

Further there are other haram acts that are usually present in professional wrestling including:

Uncovering of the 'awrah
Looking at the 'awrah of opponents
Mixing with and looking at the opposite gender
Touching the opposite gender in mixed wrestling
Hitting the face or causing physical harm
Music
Unlawful prizes
Lying
Boasting
Overindulgence and negligence of responsibilities

It is unlikely that you will be able to avoid these while having a meaningful career as a professional wrestler.
